# manually edit JSON for extractor?

Tags: import.io

In import.io, is there any way to manually edit the JSON for the extractor?  I can view it, but not edit.  I can't get manual row training to work on a page.  I created a striped-down version of the page, trained the rows, and can see the content of resultXPaths in the JSON, but there's no way to copy this to the extractor for the original page.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me.  All I had to do was make my own copy of the problem page, simplify the messy code so manual row training works, save the extractor, then point it at the original page.